# Loading dynamic javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I got problem loading dynamic JS in my script, so here the case, I have a plan to build android app with local webview something like ***webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename.html");***

Everything work fine since its only html file, but the problem came when I need to read local js contain array data that need to read by other js file.

To make it clear,

I have 100++ data_1.js data_2.js etc who contain something like

```
    data = [{
        no1:"xxx",
        no1:"xxx",
        no3:"xxx",
        ..
    }]
```

Those data will be read by one of my js script and display it on html file, basically I only need 1 data each time the page open, so its like when I open ***file://.../folder/file.html?no=1*** it will only need to read data_1.js, ***file://.../folder/file.html?no=2*** it will only need to read data_2.js

This is what I try to do.

#1
Using getScript("assets/data/data_"+number+".js");
This work when we use local server, when I access via ***localhost/folder/file.html?no=1*** its work, but when I access ***file://..../folder/file.html?no=1*** it not load because cors block

#2
Using ajax, result same with #1

#3
Add all data_x.js directly in file.html

```
<script src="folder/data_1.js"></script>
<script src="folder/data_2.js"></script>
<script src="folder/data_3.js"></script>
```

Its work when we access ***file://..../folder/file.html?no=1*** but the page load very slow because need to include and load whole data_x.js (more than 100++)

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Note: I don't want to connect to any server because I want the apps can be access offline so all data will be included inside the apps

Comment: that will same with the 3rd way, to big file to load each time we access that page..

Comment: any reference about that? honestly i never hear that before.

Comment: But, use es6 `import()`, here you are trying to do it like in 2012. It's okay, but we quite have everything built-in now.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `URLSearchParam` in combination with `createElement`, which is similar to your solution #3 but only loads the file from parameter `id`.

So you can also make use of: `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename.html?id=N");`

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search),
  id = urlParams.get('id');
if (id != null) {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = `folder/data_${id}.js`;
  script.onload = function() {
    // do something ...?
  }
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
At least at desktop it works fine.
[image: waterfall]

Comment: Added screenshot and changed the if condition.